# GMAT: How to Access startup file variables such as PYTHON_MODULE_PATH?

Tags: simulation, python, gmat

I use the python interface quite frequently and read-in tables of control variables created by another standalone module.  I need to be sure that a file created by the standalone python module can be found by another module that is called by the GMAT Python Interface during a mission sequence.  I'd love to have an absolute path to locate this control file on both ends, consistent regardless of the run method.

A relative path of "./module" seems to end up either in GMAT/userfunctions/python/ or GMAT/bin/ interchangeably, and sometimes in the project source tree when the development IDE is used.  I am never sure where the gnerated control file is going to end up, nor is my mission script.

If the script language had access to the PYTHON_MODULE_PATH that would be grand, since it contains the absolute path to ~/GMAT/userfunctions/python/.  Since these variables are "loaded on startup" I would think there should be a way to read their values, at least the ones with _PATH suffixes.  However, I cannot find a way to access this variable.  GMAT calls it "Nonexistant"

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't do `import os; os.getenv` ? (see also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values))

Comment: I can do this, but the environments that are stable between linux and windows are basically home and temp.  Don't want to use temp or home, because I want to place the controls file in a persistent location relative to the GMAT python user function.  What I'm looking for is a location under the GMAT install location, which on windows is user/app/local/gmat/.  The GMAT/userfunction/python folder is what I am looking for.

Comment: They don't have to be stable if you can get the path at runtime. My suggestion is to put at the beginning of your script/program something like `os.getenv("PYTHON_MODULE_PATH")` to access the variable. Together with  `pathlib` you should be able to resolve the absolute path.  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Good suggestion in general, though I would prefer not to use the "PYTHON_MODULE_PATH".  I could for instance store the file in a standard directory under the "HOME" path.  The issue occurs because prior to mission script execution, the user must call a python utility to create the control data file directly. The utility is executed with the CWD as "GMAT_ROOT_PATH/userfunctions/python/", whereas during the mission script execution, the GMAT executable executes the mission script with CWD as "GMAT_ROOT_PATH/bin/".

Comment: During Mission Script execution, the GMAT executable searches "GMAT_ROOT_PATH/bin" for the data file, whereas the data file has previously been created in the "GMAT_ROOT_PATH/plungins/python/".  That results because the utility writes the data file to "./".  If the  Mission Script variables included the "GMAT_ROOT_PATH" then I could pass the path root to the python control function during script execution.  As it stands now, python control function cannot be sure where GMAT is installed, hence what is the absolute path to the bin or plugins/python directory.

Comment: I could just use relative paths, such as "../userfunctions/python/", and that's probably what I will do for now, but that may break in a future release of GMAT should the installed directory structure change.

Comment: Addendum, I think one thing that might be confusing readers is that PYTHON_MODULE_PATH is not an os environment variable.  It is a configuration variable set from the GMAT startup file.

Comment: Oh I see; I was indeed wrongfully assuming that it was an env. variable.  Would `path lib.Path(__file__).resolve()` help you? It will give you the absolute path of the file that contains the statement. You can then use other Pathlib utilities to extract the GMAT_ROOT_PATH from there if you have some idea of the directory structure. This will also work on various platforms.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ludo.  Had not thought of this approach.  Actually used the code, 
    thispath = PurePath(__file__);  sharedfname = thispath.parent/'filename'

Comment: Sorry, I struggle with markdown. `thispath = PurePath(__file__); sharedfname = thispath.parent/'filename'`

Comment: Good that it works! You might want to put a `resolve()` in there. I guess it's technically not an answer to the question originally asked ;-)